# Why won't my VBS Spam Bot work?

Tags: vbscript

I am working on a Spam bot in VBS. However, something is wrong with the code. Whenever I run the VBS my computer lags then crashes. I know it is a bit basic, hence why I am asking the more experienced. Please give me the right code in order for it to work.

```
Option Explicit
Dim x,y,obj,v,o
Set obj=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
x=inputbox("What would you like to spam?")
v=inputbox("How many times would you like to spam?")
o=inputbox("How many seconds do you want to select the textbox?")
wscript.sleep o & 000
do until y=v
obj.SendKeys (x & "{ENTER}")
y=y+1
loop
wscript.quit
```

~ Thanks

Comment: Because there aren't enough spam bots out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A helpful tip you probably didn't notice as you did say you were quit inexperienced with VBS -

```
wscript.sleep o & 000
```

The ampersand (&) is a character with the logical equivalent of *and*, similar to *or* and *not*, in that they are logic, *and* is used in `if` statements to check whether both, for example, `foo` and `bar` are equivalenet to each other; for example:

```
variable1 = true
variable2 = true
if(variable1 & variable2) return true
else return false
```

This would return true, as both variables are set to true.

I understand you were trying to get the milliseconds from the user input of seconds. It might be better achieved by making a variable:

```
o = o * 1000;
```

Then, as you got this data in the form of string, parse it into an integer form:

```
milSeconds = CInt(o);
```

Probably a good idea to check whether `o` had non-numeric characters beforehand to prevent errors.

Hope this can help you continue working on it. Even though spam-bots are generally frowned upon here, I like to think they're a good learning exercise.